# How to debug postgres using a raw network connection?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, debugging, connection, database-connection

I'm trying to quickly debug a postgresql connection from a remote client. I would be happy just to get some sort of affirmative response from the postgres server. Is there anything in the raw protocol that will do this?

Example Node.js code:

```js
const net = require('net');
const client = new net.Socket();

const HOST = 'xxx.xxx.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com';
const PORT = 5432;

client.connect(PORT, HOST, function () {
    console.log(`>> connected to '${ HOST }:${ PORT }'`);
    // What can I write here?
    client.write('INFO\n'); // <--- ???
});

client.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('>> received: ' + data);
    client.destroy();
});

client.on('close', function () {
    console.log('>> closed');
});
```

Seeking a "hi you found me and I'm working" response.

**EDIT:**

Guys this is an exercise in understanding your tools at low level. I don't want to take any dependencies, and I'm not seeking an Node.js specific answer.

My hope for this question is that somebody who really understands the Postgres protocol spec can tell me if there's any sort of acknowledgement response to be had. I briefly looked into the spec, but could not find any such thing.

Comment: why don't you use https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres

Comment: I'm trying to debug on an AWS lambda process, and I want to use a single script without dependencies in order eliminate troubleshooting variables.

Comment: This is reinventing the wheel. The connection management for PostgreSQL is very complex, but it works fine within `node-postgres`, which is what you should be using.

Comment: A TCP connection that gets accepted is already a "hi you found me and I'm working" response. If you have a database to connect and a user to connect with you could go further but otherwise it's not clear what you expect.

Comment: Reinventing the wheel would be creating my own client library. An accepted TCP connection could be from any kind of server, and says nothing about the state of the Postgres server itself.